# Why would you convert binary to decimal?

Tags: binary, decimal

I wasn't able to find this question after searching here and on google. I'm having trouble understanding the reason for converting binary to decimal. I'm sure this sounds incredibly stupid to some, but I have trouble learning if I don't know when/ why I would apply the skill.

Comment: Because most humans can more readily read and understand decimal being the most common radix used in everyday life, and the computer's natural number system is binary. I assume you keep track of all of your finances in decimal. Wouldn't it be frustrating if any program you used to manage your finances output everything in binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting for binary to decimal , while not being useful in the computation themselves, is incredibly helpful to print human readable outputs, in low-level languages that don't provide it, or on platforms where some weird encoding not supported by the program makes it impossible to use the standard printing tools.

It is, nonetheless, not very useful more than 90% of the time.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer if it fulfills your question.